# SUMPRODUCT in row with single array doesn't give result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using `SUMPRODUCT` to give me the best 5 scores from a possible column of 16.
It showed me the result as soon as the 5th score was entered using this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(V6:V21,{1,2,3,4,5}))
```

which is perfect. I'm now trying to do the same thing within a single row using virtually the same formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(N5:Q5,{1,2,3}))
```

But it won't give me the result until all the fields are filled!
Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: I only have to fill in three and it works.

Comment: Hi Scott, yes it does, just tried it in some blank cells. Perhaps it's because  two of the cells take there numbers form the sum cells of this formula =(LARGE(L5:M5,{1})) thanks

Comment: If those are returning errors then yes all the errors will need to be dealt with before it can resolve.  Or you can change to AGGREGATE that will ignore errors.

Comment: @bigbbdriver, the only basic mistake is that you have used standard Formula instead of as Array (CSE),, your Formula should like,, `{=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(V6:V21,{1,2,3,4,5}))}` & `{=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(N5:Q5,{1,2,3}))}`. I've successfully reproduced results by using the same stuffs as a `CSE formula` ☺